# Start a thread inside another thread

Tags: android, multithreading

**INTRODUCTION**

I have a sub-class inside my main activity's class, which extends thread and is started every time the camera detectecs movement.

Inside this thread, when it dectects movement continuosly, it must start another thread which belongs to the main Activity's class.

I now it can be a bit messy but i'l explain it now in detail

**CODE**

This is a simplified version of my code that shows exactly what I mean:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //...

    public Runnable SpeechWhenMotion = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        // Do stuff here

        }
    }

    private static final class DetectionThread extends Thread {

    //...

    @Override
        public void run() {

        //...
        //START "SpeechWhenMotion" HERE! 

        }
    }
}
```

**QUESTION**

So the doubt I have is, how do I start the Runnable inside the thread of the DetectionThread class?
I've tryed using a handler but I think I'm not doing it right cause it doesn't get started.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what are you trying to do. Start a new thread? Execute Runnable code in DetectionThread? Execute Runnable code on UI thread?

Answer (score 2):

If you really need SpeechWhenMotion runnable to be nester class of MainActivity you need to provide link of MainActivity or SpeechWhenMotion instance to DetectionThread class:

```
 private static final class DetectionThread extends Thread {

    private Runnable mSpeechWhenMotionRunnable;

    //...
 }
```

then, when you create DetectionThread assign SpeechWhenMotion to it from main activity

```
DetectionThread detectionThread = new DetectionThread();
detectionThread.mSpeechWhenMotionRunnable = SpeechWhenMotion;
```

And finally, call start new thread inside DetectionThread:

```
   //START "SpeechWhenMotion" HERE! 
   new Thread(mSpeechWhenMotionRunnable).start();
```

Comment: I do it this way and It seems to work, so thanks... Just one question more... I've seen that the runnable runs one time and then stops... what would be the way to make it run continuosly until I set it to stop?

Comment: Yes, method run of any runnable is called once and when it returns - thread dies. So you have several options, depending of what you are trying to achieve:

Comment: 1) You can put endless loop inside SpeechWhenMotion's run method and call Thread.interrupt() on new Thread object, you created for this runnable

2) Put exit condition inside loop in runnable

3) Make endless loop with such body 
  Thread speechThread = new Thread(mSpeechWhenMotionRunnable).start();
speechThread.join()

it is actually, the same as 2 solution except it will be performed on the DetectionThread

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out and this works rather smoothly:

```
new Thread(SpeechWhenMotion).start();
```

Comment: `run()` is almost always the non-intended method to call on a thread. Use `start()`.

Comment: Damn. That's what I intended to do. I corrected my answer above.